# HTML5 <figure> margin/padding

Tags: html, css

It seems that the HTML5 element `figure` adds some margin/padding if there is an image inside it. If you add a border around the figure you can see a small padding inside the element.

```
<figure>
    <img src="image" alt="" />
</figure>
```

I reset all the margins and paddings with CSS by writing `* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }`

Anyone know how to handle it? Please take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/74Q98/

Comment: It's not localized to `figure`: http://jsfiddle.net/74Q98/2/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not a `<figure>` bug - it's a normal behavior of the `<img>` element

To fix it try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/74Q98/1/)

```
img {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**UPDATE**

By default any image rendered as inline (like a text), so the little extra space underneath is the space that all text lines have (i.e. for `q`, `p` etc.)

The above answer combines 2 methods of fixing the issue. So basically you can use just one of those:

```
img { display: block; }
```

or

```
img { vertical-align: top; }
```

Comment: I'm curious, since `vertical-align: bottom;` or `middle` also produce the same result (and the `display: block;` doesn't seem to be necessary): what is the reason for this behavior? Why does `vertical-align: baseline;` produce the extra space?

Comment: Aha I see, it lines up perfectly with the text's actual letters: http://jsfiddle.net/74Q98/3/

Comment: total opinion: all of the above work, but I prefer vertical-align: bottom; - it just seems to better describe what I want to accomplish...  I don't like display block, because I am totally changing how the image behaves in the flow...