# <figure> adds unwanted margin/padding

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to use the `<figure>`-element. So far so good and hopefully it'll make my website more SEO.

But! There is this thing where it adds an extra margin/padding (although all of them are set as `margin:0; padding:0;`). It's not the `<figcaption>` because that's placed above the `<img>` within the `<figure>`.

Can anyone explain me how to fix this? After some research I know that if you replace the `<figure>` with a regular `<div>`, it'll behave normally. But than there's no need for the `<figure>`-element at all.

A little Fiddle for the ones that ask for it: https://jsfiddle.net/jn2geLmy/1/

Comment: Can you please share a jsfiddle with your code, that will help you get some answers from here...

Comment: Check out this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182617/html5-figure-margin-padding?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your images inside the `figure`s like as `block` like so:

```
 display: block;
```

to remove the unwanted margin. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/jn2geLmy/2/)

Comment: It's weird because I've never had this issue if I place an `<img>` outside of the `<figure>`-element. But it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:block` in image in figure.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jn2geLmy/1/)